# lanzador ubuntu boton derecho

Tags: ubuntu

Estoy tratando de crear accesos directos a carpetas internas que tengo, en mi escritorio de ubuntu 17. Antes de reinstalar ubuntu me aparecia, al hacer click sobre un elemento, boton derecho, un menu y dentro de las opciones del mismo una que era 'crear lanzador', pero ahora que reinstale no aparece. No se como habilitar para que vuelva a aparecer esta opcion, busqué a full pero todo lo que aparece son metodos que tardan eternidades con comandos gnome, que tardan 2 minutos para hacer un simple atajo que deberia llevar 1/2 segundo. Agradecere enormemente algun experto en linux que me saque de la oscuridad.

Comment: Talvez este recurso le puede ayudar https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1896666

Comment: no, no es lo que busco, pero igual gracias